# C++ Microphone input

Tags: c++

I know there are tons of questions about this already After Doing tons of research, so don't bother redirecting to another question.

I need to capture the stream and get the microphone stream data such as frequency pitch all of that good stuff.

I have heard of DirectX audio, and OPENAL but have not tested them because they do not look entirely like what i need.

I need direct Access to the microphone,
I am starting to think i need to write a driver for this.

Assist me in this please.

Comment: "Assist me in this please." Why...? And why do you feel that DirectX and OpenAL isn't suitable for your needs?

Comment: Not until you give us more information about your platform or show us what you have so far.

Answer (score 4):

Direct access to the microphone does not give you "frequency, pitch, all of that good stuff".  First, frequency and pitch are the same.  Secondly, they are found by processing microphone data.

The raw microphone data consists of a sequence of periodically measured voltage samples.  A "pure" sound would be a sine function, but of course there are always background noise and harmonics and measurement noise.

The [`waveInOpen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713735%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function is where you start if you want low-level access to data from the microphone on Windows.

Google knows about a number of "waveInOpen samples", but here's one that looks like above-average quality:

- http://www.techmind.org/wave/